# Is it possible to have function extensions on lambdas?

Tags: lambda, exception, kotlin

I'd like to check if some code throws a determined exception.

In particular, for my case, I'd like to write like:

`{shaderCodeOf(gl, this::class.java, data + "$FRAGMENT_FAIL.frag")} shallThrow GLException::java.class`

I tried to write

`infix fun (() -> Unit).shallThrow(java: Class<*>)`

but I didn't have much success..

any idea, guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no problems with declaring extension functions on lambdas.

```
infix fun (()->Unit).shallThrow(java: Class<out Throwable>) {
    // do whatever you need                 ^ you mean this, didn't you?
}
```

Then:

```
{} shallThrow RuntimeException::class.java
```

Comment: How can I check the exception type in there?

Comment: @elect try `java.isInstance(e)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 3):

Not a straight answer to your question (receiver methods on lambdas), but there's an alternative implementation you could use:

```
inline fun <reified T: Throwable> assertThrows(fn: (() -> Unit)) {
    try {
        fn()
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        if (e is T) {
            return
        } else {
            fail("Expected ${T::class} but caught ${e::class}")
        }
    }
    fail("Expected ${T::class} but caught nothing.")
}
```

Which you can use as `assertThrows<MyException> { doStuff(); }`